# ControlValueAccessor on Custom Form Component in Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, mapbox

I implemented a dynamic form based on [this tutorial](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-dynamic-components-forms). I'd like to add simple text inputs and a custom component (Mapbox GL JS) to a dynamic form.

My problem is that I can not access the Mapbox data. The Mapbox component implements a ControlValueAccessor but I don't know how to pass the information to the form.

I created a StackBlitz where you can find my setup: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrkftm

My goal was to display the form information (text input and Mapbox marker location) below the form.

I don't know where to add `[formControlName]="config.name"`. Currently it's in the `map.component.ts` but I guess it needs to be implemented on the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors on load:
I could fix some of them. In DynamicFormComponent you should use your config to create all the controls:

```
 createGroup() {
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    this.config.forEach(control => {
      group.addControl(control.name, this.createControl(control))
    });
    return group;
  }
```

MapComponent: you should write the result back into the form

```
 _onChange = (geometry: any) => {
     ... 
     this.group.patchValue({[this.config.name]: this.geometry});
 }
```

However some error still exists, check console.
If you change map.component.html to:

```
<div>
    <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
    <div #map class="map"></div>
</div>
```

all error disappears, since it is not a valid angular value accessor.